# CSS: Wrap Text From Multiple Rows Around Floating Element

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to have a page of aligned labels and descriptions where there is a single image on top of the page,

here is what is happening currently...
[image: What is happening]

here is what I want to happen (I used the above image as the 'image' in this... I hope that is not confusing.

[image]

Is it possible for me to wrap multiple divs with text in them around this image while maintaining vertical alignment of the names to their value? I am a little rusty in my CSS but I am not sure this can be done (at least not in the way I set it up here)

```css
        .content-col {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            padding: 2px 2px 2px;
        }

        .content-key {
            width: 30%;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .content-value {
            width: 65%;
        }

        hr{
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .imageDiv{
            background-color: pink;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            object-fit: contain;
            float: right;
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="imageDiv" ></div>

<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="content-col content-key">Attribute Name Test</div>
    <div class="content-col content-value">
        This is where the attribute value and description will be.
        This is where the attribute value and description will be.
        This is where the attribute value and description will be.
        This is where the attribute value and description will be.
        This is where the attribute value and description will be.
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="content-col content-key">Attribute Name Test</div>
    <div class="content-col content-value">
        This is where the attribute value and description will be.
        This is where the attribute value and description will be.
        This is where the attribute value and description will be.
        This is where the attribute value and description will be.
        This is where the attribute value and description will be.
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
```

Comment: the image needs to be floated which works correctly. As I understand, the "title" should be at left side of the text block. not inline an not on top of it. You can achieve that behavior either with flex-box or css-grid. However it seems to me, that this is a learning assignment, are there any limitatiuons to what you are allowed to use?

Comment: Whatever I do needs to be able to be rendered as a pdf, I am not sure if there are any strict limitations, I guess I could test, but I would rather keep it to straight CSS without any kind of libraries or add-ons if I can help it.